# Monitor connection status of VPN and reconnect if disconnected

Tags: unix, vpn, launchd

I can connect to my VPN with :

`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect SERVER`

I can check the connection status with:

`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn status`

That gives a printout of

```
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 4.3.03086) .

Copyright (c) 2004 - 2016 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


  >> state: Connected
  >> state: Connected
  >> state: Connected
  >> notice: Connected to Not Available.
  >> registered with local VPN subsystem.
VPN>
```

What's the most Mac-tastic way of always monitoring whether the VPN is connected and reconnecting it if it's not?  Don't be `bash`ful.

Comment: (feel free to use `bash`)

Answer (score 3):

here's how i did it:

save the following to `/usr/local/bin/vpn`

```
if [[ "{$(/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn status)[0]}" == *"Disconnected"* ]]; then
    /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect SERVER
fi
```

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vpn`

save the following to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.utilities.vpn.plist`

`<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.whatever.vpn</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/vpn</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
</plist>`

load it into `launchd`:

`launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.whatever.vpn.plist`

check that it's there:

`launchctl list | grep whatever`